# How can i save the information from a jtable into mysql

Tags: mysql, netbeans-8

This error comes out every time:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2

**code**

````
            int fila2 = this.rSTableMetro4.getRowCount();
            int fila3 = this.rSTableMetro3.getRowCount();
            int fila5 = this.rSTableMetro5.getRowCount();
            int fila4 = this.td7.getRowCount();
            connect cnx = new connect();
            com.mysql.jdbc.Connection registro = cnx.connect();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO rpe (dom1,dom2,dom3,dom4,sexo,edad,dom) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            System.out.println("HERE NOW");
            try {
                PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) registro.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, this.rSTableMetro2.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
                pst.setString(2, this.rSTableMetro4.getValueAt(fila2, 0).toString());
                pst.setString(3, this.rSTableMetro3.getValueAt(fila3, 0).toString());
                pst.setString(4, this.rSTableMetro5.getValueAt(fila5, 0).toString());
                pst.setString(5, this.td7.getValueAt(fila4,0).toString());
                pst.setString(6, this.td7.getValueAt(fila4,1).toString());
                pst.setString(7, this.td7.getValueAt(fila4,2).toString());
            ```
````

Comment: which line does it occur? What are the `filaX` values?

Comment: from this line:pst.setString(1, this.rSTableMetro2.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());

Comment: @Edx please specify that information in the question such as "error type" on line "this.post()" to make the post clear and informative.